# strange bool value returned from a function in c# on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

In my c# code, I have

```
bool aBoolVar = csfunction().
```

The csfunction() uses pinvoke to call a c++ function in the library which returns a bool value of ture. I use

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
```

for the bool value marshaling. This works well on mono 3.12. But after I upgraded the mono to 4.6.

```
if (aBoolVar == true)
```

is still successful but

```
aBoolVal.Equals(true)
```

failed constantly. I changed `UnmanagedType.U1` to other two types for bool values but it didn't work. I printed `Convert.ToInt32(aBoolVar)` and it was 1. But I still suspect it is not 1. I wanted to use DevelopMono to check the memory layout of `aBoolVar` bit by bit, but I had trouble of dependency when I install the DevelopMono.

Can anybody help me to figure out why `aBoolVal.Equals(true)` was failed? If anybody had good experience of using DevelopMono to check the memory layout, please let me know either. I'll try to install DevelopMono and debug.

Thanks in advance.

qwang

Comment: Just an idea. From native C, the booalens are represented by unsigned char data type. I am not sure how this is relevant to C# and your case in general, but perhaps the returned bool in your case is a byte which value is not 0 and not 1 but something else?

Comment: I have been suspecting the returned value is neither 0 nor 1, but I can't prove it. Because I don't have a good tool for debugging.

Comment: I found the answer by myself. The c function returned 2. The Equals() implemented in 3.12 is lenient. So it returned True on mono 2.12. But Equals() implementation in 4.6 is more strict. It returned False.

Comment: Therefore, test always against FALSE!